# cloudantNoSQLDB: Service broker Error 400

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to delete an Unbound service from IBM Bluemix dashboard and got the following error:

> Service instance cloudantNoSQLDB: Service broker error:
>   {"description"=>"Error 400 received from broker url
>   https://cloudantbroker.ng.bluemix.net/v2/service_instances/902f9751-227d-45e6-8b5b-05d72f0f70c8?plan_id=cloudant-shared&service_id=cloudant"}

Checked the [status](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status) which says the issue has been resolved. So tried again, and still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue should now be resolved. In this case I think all you can do is to open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget or sending an email to support@bluemix.net: in this way you'll involve Bluemix support team in checking and fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Submitted a support request,